# Azure VM - Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved standardDv2Family Cores quota

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Would like to increase the capacity of existing Azure Vitrual Machine Scale set.

Issued below command:

```
az vmss scale --name test --new-capacity 5 --resource-group testrg
```

[Exception Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW2sl.png)

> Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved
> **standardDv2Family** Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: XXXXX, Current Limit: 10, Current
> Usage: 10, Additional Required: 1, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 11.
> Submit a request for Quota increase at
> https://aka.ms/ProdportalCRP/?#create/Microsoft.Support/Parameters/%7B%22subId%22:%2XXXXX-8RRRca-4f0a-9e39-9XXXXXXX%22,%22pesId%22:%2206bfd9d3-5DDb-d5c6-5FF2-DDDDDD00dec89%22,%22supportTopicId%22:%22e12e3d1d-7fa0-af33-c6d0-3c50df9658a3%22%7D
> by specifying parameters listed in the ‘Details’ section for
> deployment to succeed.

The above error message says "Current usage: 10" but the Azure poratl screenshot shows only 4 VMs & 1 VMSS
[Azure portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDvPU.png)

As per Azure portal for "xxxx" location, The total VMs provisioned is 4 standalone VMs & 4 more VMs under VMSS, total is not 10 as the exception says but it is 8 VMs.

Where would be rest 2 VMs hiding?

**(OR)**

How to find out those other 2 extra VMs reported by the exception? So that, they can be deleted to stay within the quota of allocated 10 standardDv2Family VMs per location.

Gone through this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests

Still can't able to understand what is quota & how it is applied & how to remove it.

Some expertise opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Core quotas for virtual machines and virtual machine scale sets are arranged in two tiers for each subscription, in each region. The first tier is the Total Regional vCPUs, and the second tier is the various VM size family cores such as the D-series vCPUs. Any time a new VM is deployed the vCPUs for the VM must not exceed the vCPU quota for the VM size family or the total regional vCPU quota. If either of those quotas are exceeded, the VM deployment will not be allowed. Meanwhile, different VM sizes need different numbers of cores.

If you want to know the cores' number of different size, you can use `Get-AzVMSize` to check if.

```
Get-AzVMSize -Location 'southeastasia'
```

[image]

Besides, you can use the `Get-AzVMUsage` cmdlet to check on your quota usage

```
Get-AzVMUsage -Location `southeastasia`
```

[image]

Comment: Got it. So, increasing Core quotas for virtual machines (via support request)  attracts any charges?